# updating cURL on Heroku

Tags: curl, heroku

I am trying to figure out how to update the version of cURL on Heroku, but am very new to Heroku and entire buildpack system.  Does anyone know how I could update just the cURL utility?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can see which packages are installed on [Heroku's Ubuntu Packages on Cedar and Cedar-14](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-ubuntu-packages) page. It looks like Cedar has curl 7.19.7-1ubuntu1.11 and cedar-14 has 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.5.

If your app is running cedar and you want the 7.35.0 on cedar-14, run `heroku stack:set cedar-14` to upgrade. If you want a version > 7.35.0, you could try deploying the curl binary in a `/bin` folder within your repository and accessing that directly.